# Перевод по выборам модераторов

Tags: поддержка, статус-завершено, локализация, термины, выборы

К выборам, имхо, более применимы термины, связанные с кандидатами, а не с "номинантами".
Мои предложения:

- nominate - выдвинуть [кандидата]
- nominees - кандидаты
- nomination - выдвижение кандидатов

Исходя из того, что выборы делятся на три этапа. Фаза - неудачное слово.

- phase - этап
- Election - голосование (как этап выборов)
- Primary - предварительное голосование (там можно за или против голосовать, потом будет этап election)

**UPD**
Процесс примерно такой. если кто разбирается лучше, пусть поправят.

1й этап. nomination. выдвижение кандидатов их обсуждение в комментариях.
2й этап. primary - предварительное голосование. это когда голосуют и за и против, выбирая первые N, которе будут участвовать в итоговом голосовании. Комментарии уже закрыты на этом этапе.
3й этап. election - собственно выборы. когда сообщество голосует за прошедших primary N кандидатов.

Второй этап может быть пропущен, если кандидатов меньше N.
после выборов используется хитрый метод ([Meek STV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_single_transferable_votes#Meek)) выявления победителей.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Выбранный вариант*.

- nominate - выдвинуть [кандидата]
- nominees - кандидаты
- Nomination - выдвижение кандидатов
- phase - этап
- Election - голосование (как этап выборов)
- Primary - предварительное голосование